# MongoSocketException Mongodb Java Connected problem

Tags: java, mongodb

i have problem with mongodb java connected error.i have install robo mongo it is working but.i connect with java i got these error. i have added mongo db jar file **mongo-java-driver-3.12.11.jar** file in to the libriaries.what is error i got i attached below.

```
 com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongodb://localhost:27017:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
May 23, 2022 7:37:02 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb://localhost:27017:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb://localhost:27017
```

what i tried so far i attached below.

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;


public class MongoJava {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  
            MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017"); 
            DB database = mongo.getDB("school");
            System.out.println("Success");

           
        }
        
       
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `mongodb://localhost:27017:27017` may be your mongodb instance is not running on this port?

Comment: it port running i attached the screen image above please check